# R: using for loops, apply, and which to select data based on date

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

Suppose I have a vector of dates, generated by the following command:

```
dts<-seq(as.Date("2014-09-10"),as.Date("2014-09-20"),by="Days")
```

I also have a data frame of user ids and dates (where the timestamp column is of class Date):

```
>df
respondent_id  timestamp
           12 2014-09-19
           13 2014-09-11
           12 2014-09-20
            9 2014-09-16
           13 2014-09-15
           12 2014-09-18
           9  2014-09-15
           9  2014-09-16
           12 2014-09-20
           13 2014-09-14
```

My end goal here is to count up all the users who have a timestamp with in 24 hours of another timestamp, over the range of dts. I would get something like this in the end:

```
>final

Date        Count
2014-09-10   0
2014-09-11   0
2014-09-12   0
2014-09-13   0
2014-09-14   0
2014-09-15   1
2014-09-16   2
2014-09-17   0
2014-09-18   0
2014-09-19   1
2014-09-20   1
```

My initial approach is to loop through dts and use a combination of `apply()` and `which()` to select the data:

```
for (i in 1:length(dts)){
day1         <- apply(as.data.frame(df$timestamp),1,function(x) which(x>=dts[i]-1 & x<=dts[i],arr.ind=TRUE))
}
tmp1         <- df[day1,]
tmp11        <- as.data.frame(table(tdf$timestamp))
names(tmp11) <- c("Date","Count")
tmp11$Date   <- as.Date(tmp11$Date)
```

But this is unsuccessful. The variable day1 is a list and thus cannot be used to subset a data frame. Using the command `unlist()` as well as `as.data.frame()` generates a data frame that does contain the correct indices of df. I'm still transitioning into using `apply()` in place of a loop so any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
dts<-data.table(timestamp=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-10"),as.POSIXct("2014-09-20"),by=60*60*24),key="timestamp")
df<-data.table(respondent_id=c(12,13,12,9,13,12,9,9,12,13),timestamp=as.POSIXct(c("2014-09-19",
                                                                   "2014-09-11",
                                                                   "2014-09-20",
                                                                   "2014-09-16",
                                                                   "2014-09-15",
                                                                   "2014-09-18",
                                                                   "2014-09-15",
                                                                   "2014-09-16",
                                                                   "2014-09-20",
                                                                   "2014-09-14")),key="timestamp")

#don't do this: df[dts,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,.N-1,by=timestamp]

#do this:
df[,.N,by=timestamp] # this gets you the nonzero counts
dts[!(timestamp %in% df[,timestamp]),list(timestamp,N=0)] #this gives you all the missing dates where count is 0

rbindlist(list(df[,.N,by=timestamp],dts[!(timestamp %in% df[,timestamp]),list(timestamp,count=0)]))[order(timestamp)] #this puts them all together.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I am to run your solution successfully on the sample data I provided, I think there are some nuances I do not understand as I'm not able to generalize this solution to a larger dataset. In your final line, what does the .N-1 indicate? Does 1 represent one day (24 hours)? Also, when I use `tmp<-data.table(df,key=timestamp)` followed by `tmp$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(tmp$timestamp)` my timestamp instances are a date followed by a time, where that time is the same for all entries (17:00:00 PDT). Could this cause an issue in subsetting?

Comment: @JMeo `data.table` is a pretty robust package so I recommend reading the vignettes and manual on it.  The syntax is like this [conditions, columns, grouping].  The `.N` signifies to count how many rows are in a grouping.

Comment: @JMeo I am assuming you're using `lubridate` to handle your dates which I think `data.table` can work with so don't both converting your dates to `POSIXct`.  I know `data.table` can't handle `POSIXlt` object since those are lists.  If you want to use `POSIXct` objects and it's shifting the time to 1700 then I'm guessing it has to do with timezones and localization so add `tz="UTC"` to the end of `as.POSIXct()`